# Duplication of a dataframe for each month

Tags: r, duplicates

I have this data:

```
  month shop product
1     1    1       2
2     1    1       3
3     1    2       4
4     1    3       4
5     1    4       5
```

I want to duplicate it regarding the next 12 month. Since the data set has 5 rows there have to be 60 rows after the duplication.

So it has to look like this:

```
  month shop product
1     1    1       2
2     1    1       3
3     1    2       4
4     1    3       4
5     1    4       5
6     2    1       2
7     2    1       3
8     2    2       4
9     2    3       4
10    2    4       5
11    3    1       2
...
```

I tried to use `expand.grid`:

```
d_expand = expand.grid(month = c(1:12), shop = d$shop, product = d$product)
```

But I get 300 rows since every combination is used.

```
library(dplyr)

glimpse(d_expand)

Observations: 300
Variables: 3
$ month   <int> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,...
$ shop    <dbl> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,...
$ product <dbl> 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,...
```

Is there a possibility to extend the data set, so that only those combinations are duplicated which actually occur in the data.

```
dput(d)
structure(list(month = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), shop = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 
4), product = c(2, 3, 4, 4, 5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do

```
data.frame(month = rep(1:12, each = 5), shop = rep(d$shop, 12), 
           product = rep(d$product, 12))


#   month shop product
#1      1    1       2
#2      1    1       3
#3      1    2       4
#4      1    3       4
#5      1    4       5
#6      2    1       2
#7      2    1       3
#8      2    2       4
#9      2    3       4
#10     2    4       5
#11     3    1       2
#.....
```

Or if you have more number of columns and don't want to type each column manually a general solution would be to ignore the `month` column and repeat every row 12 times and use recycling technique to fill `month` column from `1:12`

```
cbind(month = 1:12, d[rep(seq_len(nrow(d)), each = 12), -1])
```

---

We can also use `tidyr::crossing`

```
tidyr::crossing(month = 1:12, d[-1])
```

Comment: Phew, `tidyr::crossing` is like 5 times slower.

Comment: @zx8754 but it's from `tidyverse` ;-)

Comment: To be fair it does look succinct compared to base. Depending on needs fast vs pretty.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `complete`

```
library(tidyverse)
complete(d, month = 1:12, nesting(shop, product))
# A tibble: 60 x 3
#   month  shop product
#   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1     1     1       2
# 2     1     1       3
# 3     1     2       4
# 4     1     3       4
# 5     1     4       5
# 6     2     1       2
# 7     2     1       3
# 8     2     2       4
# 9     2     3       4
#10     2     4       5
# … with 50 more rows
```

---

Another option is `expand.grid`, but create a data.frame with the sequence of rows instead of the columns

```
d1 <-  expand.grid(month = 1:12, rn = seq_len(nrow(d)))
```

and then use the 'rn' for indexing

```
cbind(d1['month'], d[-1][d1$rn,])
```